# Twice deferred EL expression in JSF

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a Menu object, that has a method getCommand(), returning EL expression. When I construct MenuModel from bean, I simply use

```
menuitem.setCommand(menu.getCommand());
```

and it works fine.

Now, I need to construct a commandButton, but when I'm writing

```html
<p:commandButton icon="#{menu.icon}" value="#{menu.name}" action="#{menu.getCommand}"
```

the button returns the EL expression stored in menu instead of calling it. Any ideas how can I solve this problem?

Comment: If `getCommand` is a method then use it like `getCommand()`, otherwise if it is a getter for property `command` this use it as it as.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful for others, so I'm posting solution I came to ([this page](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html) was very helpful):

I implemented a method, that will resolve the expression stored in *menu.getCommand()* using ELResolver:

```
public String doAction(String command) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Object result = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(context.getELContext(), command, Object.class).getValue(context.getELContext());
    return result.toString();
}
```

Then call it in commandButton:

```html
<p:commandButton icon="#{menu.icon}" value="#{menu.name}" action="#{bean.doAction(menu.getCommand)}"
```